# how to get svg of highcharts using div id?

Tags: jquery, highcharts

```
<script>
   $(function () {


        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'funnel',
                marginRight: 100
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Sales funnel'
            },
            plotArea: {
                shadow: null,
                borderWidth: null,
                backgroundColor: null
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
                        color: 'black',
                        softConnector: true
                    },
                    neckWidth: '30%',
                    neckHeight: '25%'

                    //-- Other available options
                    // height: pixels or percent
                    // width: pixels or percent
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Unique users',
                data: [
                    ['Website visits',   15654],
                    ['Downloads',       4064],
                    ['Requested price list', 1987],
                    ['Invoice sent',    976],
                    ['Finalized',    846]
                ]
            }]
        });

        // Add the jQuery UI resizin
        var container = $('#container')[0];
        $('#resizer').resizable({
            // On resize, set the chart size to that of the 
            // resizer minus padding. If your chart has a lot of data or other
            // content, the redrawing might be slow. In that case, we recommend 
            // that you use the 'stop' event instead of 'resize'.
            resize: function() {
                chart.setSize(
                    this.offsetWidth - 20, 
                    this.offsetHeight - 20,
                    false
                );
            }
        });
    });​
    </script>
```

I did a sample funnel chart using highcharts so i dont wanna use highcharts export feature. I need to get the svg of the below chart using the div id.
Below code is for the div part of the chart it will render the chart in this div.

```
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px;">
    </div>



    using div id "container" i need to get svg of the chart.
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a method called `getSVG` which can be used if you have your `chart` instance.

`var svg = chart.getSVG();`

*Reference*

- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#object-Chart

Comment: If someone get's an error because Highcharts doesn't have a getSVG function, you're probably missing the [export module](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview).

Answer (score 1):

You can get instance of `highcharts` using the container and then call `getSVG()` method on it. From sample in your question, it'll look like below:

`$('#container').highcharts().getSVG();`

Reference
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.getSVG

Answer (score 0):

you can get it simple by using $('#container .highcharts-container').html();

this will give the whole svg as string, with which you can play.

you can also get extending highcharts export js and use the following function

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.getSVG()

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `Ricardo Alvaro Lohmann`'s Answer, I must point out that although Highcharts `getSVG()` does return a svg of the existing chart, It **does not** return the exact same svg that is generated in the browser, It changes the scaling values in almost all height, width, x, y's values and sometimes it also skips some of the points in y-axis as well. Please check the [snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/8w2n1pfb/) to find mismatch.

If you compare the difference in svg by inspecting the html vs svg in the console(from getSVG()) after clicking the button. You will also see the mismatch if you download svg from the button on top right, notice the y axis value in the downloaded image vs the one in browser.

In order to get the exact same SVG which is generated by highchart `XMLSerializer` can be used.

```
var svgDoms = document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-root');
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var serializedSvgString = serializer.serializeToString(svgDoms[0]);
```

This will work for the snippet I provided.